# Rotate is not working when it's called on button click Event

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, 2d

The rotate function is working on by default rendering, but on button click event the rotate function is not working !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body { margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        }
        </style>
<body>
<script>
  function Rotatectx()
    {
      var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
      ctx.lineWidth=10;
      ctx.rotate(10*Math.PI/180); //This rotate is not getting called
    }
</script>
 <button onclick="Rotatectx()">Rotate</button>
<div id="IDD">

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
    </div>

<script>

    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

//ctx.rotate(10*Math.PI/180); enable this to get a rotation.

    ctx.fillStyle='#FF3399';
    ctx.shadowBlur=15;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX=10;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY=10;
    ctx.shadowColor="#009933";
    ctx.translate(200,100);
    var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);
    gradient.addColorStop("0","magenta");
    gradient.addColorStop("0.5","blue");
    gradient.addColorStop("1.0","red");

    ctx.strokeStyle=gradient;
    ctx.lineWidth=5;

    var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(238, 50, 10, 238, 50, 300);
    grd.addColorStop(0, '#8ED6FF');
    grd.addColorStop(1, '#004CB3');
    // for custom shape.
    ctx.moveTo(120,20);
    ctx.lineTo(30,90);
    ctx.lineTo(30,130);
    ctx.lineTo(120,200);
    ctx.lineTo(210,130);
    ctx.lineTo(210,90);
    ctx.lineTo(120,20);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillstyle= '#8ED6FF';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-factor your code a little bit. Setting rotate will only affect the *next* drawings.

Try something like this:

### [Online demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/C5uYV/)

```
/// place these in global context once
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function Rotatectx() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);         /// clear canvas with
                                                  /// current rotation.
  ctx.translate(c.width * 0.5, c.height * 0.5);   /// translate to center first
  ctx.rotate(10 * Math.PI/180);                   /// rotate
  ctx.translate(-c.width * 0.5, -c.height * 0.5); /// translate back

  render();  /// call the drawing
}
```

Unless you want the image to be rotated by its corner we need to translate to center first, then rotate and translate back. This is because rotation (transformation) matrix always rotate around origin (0,0).

Then put your drawing that you want to update in a method which makes it easy to reproduce. You need to clear the canvas each time as well - for now I put this into your rotation method as the transformation matrix also affect the `clearRect()` method. You might want to re-factor further by having a `clear()` method in your script.

```
function render() {

    ctx.save();         /// this saves current state

    ctx.beginPath();    /// important!

    ctx.fillStyle='#FF3399';
    ctx.shadowBlur=15;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX=10;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY=10;
    ctx.shadowColor="#009933";

    ctx.translate(200,100);

    var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);
    gradient.addColorStop("0","magenta");
    gradient.addColorStop("0.5","blue");
    gradient.addColorStop("1.0","red");

    ctx.strokeStyle=gradient;
    ctx.lineWidth=5;

    var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(238, 50, 10, 238, 50, 300);
    grd.addColorStop(0, '#8ED6FF');
    grd.addColorStop(1, '#004CB3');

    // for custom shape.
    ctx.moveTo(120,20);
    ctx.lineTo(30,90);
    ctx.lineTo(30,130);
    ctx.lineTo(120,200);
    ctx.lineTo(210,130);
    ctx.lineTo(210,90);
    ctx.lineTo(120,20);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillstyle= '#8ED6FF';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.restore();   /// this restore to previous state
}
```

Due to the code using a local translate, set shadow etc. a `save()`/`restore()` may be an advantage here as the restore will "reset" all these settings after the render is done. If not the added translate you have in there as well as shadow will affect the next things you draw to the canvas.

To reset the rotation you can do:

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
ctx.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `context.rotate` function doesn't affect anything you've drawn on the canvas before. It only affects what you draw afterwards. When you want to rotate the existing content of a canvas, you have to erase it, rotate it and then draw everything again.

Alternatively you could use [CSS3 transformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) in the style of the canvas-element to rotate the display of the canvas in the document. But keep in mind that CSS transformation is a non-standard feature which is still in working-draft status.